# Azure data factory: Using output of Rest in copy data activity in next activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have copy data activity which copies data from Rest to SQL Server. Rest returns a json response. I need to have another Web activity after success of copy data. This activity needs data from previous rest api response (which is part of copy data). Any idea how we can achieve this.

I have tried using

```
@{activity('ACTIVITY_NAME').output.<json_field_from_response>
```

I get following error.

```
{
    "errorCode": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "The expression 'activity('ACTIVITY_NAME').output.batch_id' cannot be evaluated because property 'batch_id' doesn't exist, available properties are 'dataRead, dataWritten, rowsRead, rowsCopied, copyDuration, throughput, errors, effectiveIntegrationRuntime, usedDataIntegrationUnits, usedParallelCopies, executionDetails'.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Web1"
}
```

I am hoping there will be some way in dataset or pipeline to set variable to be used later. But I am not able to find it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [lookup activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) and get the data from [lookup output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity#use-the-lookup-activity-result-in-a-subsequent-activity).

Comment: Do you have any example on how it can be used with copy data? Documentation is not very clear.